# Create Par1 x Par2 UI table view out of SQL Table(par1, par2, value)

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

How to create **Par1 x Par2** table output (so that you can present it to user in human-friendly and senseful way) out of SQL Table(par1, par2, value). Example:

[image]

I don't have much code and none worth presenting and I assume there's a standard way to do it. I started trying to generate the row heading and adding `UNION` with a `WITH` window function, but started to struggle straight away.

Test data sample:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable(
    [Par1] [int] NULL,
    [Par2] [int] NULL,
    [Val] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO TestTable (Par1, Par2, Val)
VALUES
    (1, 20  , 104),
    (1, 40  , 105),
    (1, 60  , 110),
    (1, 80  , 115),
    (1, 100 , 148),
    (1, 120 , 150),
    (2, 20  , 162),
    (2, 40  , 163),
    (2, 60  , 174),
    (2, 80  , 188),
    (2, 100 , 192),
    (2, 120 , 196),
    (3, 20  , 200),
    (3, 40  , 217),
    (3, 60  , 231),
    (3, 80  , 255),
    (3, 100 , 279),
    (3, 120 , 283),
    (4, 20  , 284),
    (4, 40  , 284),
    (4, 60  , 286),
    (4, 80  , 288),
    (4, 100 , 297),
    (4, 120 , 300),
    (5, 20  , 303),
    (5, 40  , 305),
    (5, 60  , 307),
    (5, 80  , 325),
    (5, 100 , 337),
    (5, 120 , 349)
```

Side note: I'm sure this had to be answered before, however I'm unable to google any relevant answers. Searching for a strings like "CREATE TABLE VIEW" gives totally unrelevant results... :-). I'm sorry if it's me not being able to find right wording.

Answer (score 0):

You want conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT Par1, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Par2 = 20 THEN Val ELSE 0 END) AS 20_Val,
       . . .
       SUM(CASE WHEN Par2 = 120 THEN Val ELSE 0 END) AS 120_Val
FROM TestTable tt
GROUP BY Par1;
```

Comment: But that is hard-coded. In reality, you don't know what and how long parameters (A x B) you have in a table. I need to do it for about two dozens of tables, it is not very feasible to type everything in. I believe it has to be achievable with i.e. with CTE `WITH`. Or did I miss your point?

Comment: Oh, and  not to forget, if a row is added into the table (a real scenario), then the code (placed in a printable Report) will fail to provide correct results.

Comment: @Oak_3260548. . . Then you need a `Dynamic SQL` Pivot.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I found some references and I'll look at it.